# Browser accepts "classic" js script-tag, but not ES6 modules — MIME error w/ Node http server

Tags: node.js, http, mime-types, es6-modules

I want to play with ES6 modules, so I decided on using Node as a simple web server to avoid all CORS related errors I first encountered when doing it locally. Now I get MIME type related errors in the browser which I can't quite grasp.

Here is my `server.js` file:

```
const http = require('http'),
      url  = require('url'),
      fs   = require('fs');

http.createServer((req, res) => {

  const q = url.parse(req.url, true),
        filename = "." + q.pathname;

  fs.readFile(filename, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      return res.end("404 Not Found");
    }  
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    return res.end();
  });

}).listen(8080);
```

If I try to access my `index.html` file in the browser, which contains the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body> 

  <!-- Works -->
  <script src="index.js"></script>

  <!-- Doesn't work -->
  <script src="module.js" type="module"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I get the following error:

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a
>   non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html".

The `type="text/javascript"` attribute has no effect on the module tag either. I have read that all ES6 modules are "deferred" by default, meaning that they don't execute before the HTML is fully parsed. I guess this is the problem, but I don't know how to modify my `server.js` file accordingly to fix it. Help is greatly appreciated! If not too unpractical, I would prefer not to pull in any NPM packages.

**EDIT:** I thought that since I accessed `http://localhost:8080/index.html` That it was correct to send a header with type `text/html`. But if I `console.log(url.parse(req.url, true));` I now see that deferred script tags trigger the `createServer` callback. The object logged explicitly shows it's the filename of the JS module.

I'll come back with a working example once I've fixed the faulty header.

**SOLUTION:** I pulled in two additional modules; path and **mime**. I used `mime.getType()` on the extension of the path returned by `url.parse()`.

```
const http = require('http'),
      url  = require('url'),
      fs   = require('fs'),
      mime = require('mime'),
      path = require('path');

http.createServer((req, res) => {

  const q = url.parse(req.url, true),
        filename = "." + q.pathname;

  fs.readFile(filename, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      return res.end("404 Not Found");
    }  
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': mime.getType(path.extname(filename))});
    res.write(data);
    return res.end();
  });

}).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
```

This would suggest that every file is served with a `text/html` mimetype.

Comment: This comment will reveal how much of a newbie I am at web servers, but anyways.. Since my URL always pointed to a html file, I thought that header would suffice. I decided to console log url.parse(req.url)` and saw that the createServer callback was triggered by module script-tags. Your comment put me on the right path, thanks!

Comment: @AudunOlsen Yea every 'file' is its own hidden HTTP request =) good luck on journey!

Answer (score 1):

You're sending back a `Content-Type: text/html` header when the browser requests your module - this isn't valid, [as per the HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#fetching-scripts):

> If any of the following conditions are met, throw a "NetworkError" DOMException:
>
> - *response*'s type is "`error`"
> - *response*'s status is not an ok status
> - The result of extracting a MIME type from response's header list is not a JavaScript MIME type

'Classic' scripts don't have this restriction, as far as I can tell.

In order to fix this, you need to send your JavaScript module back from the server with an appropriate MIME type, such as `text/javascript`:

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/javascript'});
```

I'd recommend using something like Express instead of working directly with the `http` module, though - [you can get a lot of this functionality out of the box](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html), and I believe it'll handle setting the headers for you.