# Flask: Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html"

Tags: javascript, flask

- Server: Python/Flask
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04
- Vanilla JS

```html
    <script
      type="module"
      src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/app.js') }}"
    ></script
```

I have included this script tag at the bottom of the body in the html.  For some reasons, when I run the server locally with flask run, I the following error message in browser console:

```
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

Why is the loading the wrong MIME-type.  I am not even sure if there are more details that are relevant.  I will do my best to fill in the blanks as best as I can.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.  In Flask if you import files like so

```js
import SomeClass from './utils'
```

then it will have the content-type in the header set to 'html/text' and it will error.  To fix this import it like this:

```js
import SomeClass from './utils.js'
```

and it will set the content-type header correctly

Answer (score -1):

I think adding `crossorigin = "anonymous"` will fix the problem.

I read that "Unlike classic scripts, module scripts require the use of the CORS protocol for cross-origin fetching."

```
<script
    type="module"
    src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/app.js') }}"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but no change for me :/

Comment: :( maybe this thread has the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54651811/browser-accepts-classic-js-script-tag-but-not-es6-modules-mime-error-w-nod